# local dependency in my case

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven to build my java project.

I have a library jar named `my.jar` used as my project's `dependency`. However, it is not available in the remote central repository. So, I would like to put the jar file under my project. So, I created a folder named `my_repo/` under MyProject.

The directory structure of MyProject looks like this:

```
MyProject/
   my_repo/
       my.jar
   pom.xml
```

But I have no idea how could I define my pom to find this particular dependency under `MyProject/my_repo/my.jar` ?

Could someone please help me for my scenario? By the way, I have also some other dependencies defined in my pom.xml, they are available in the remote central repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the system scope. ${basedir} is the directory of your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>..</artifactId>
    <groupId>..</groupId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/my_repo/my.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where should I define the basedir variable?

Comment: You dont need to define the variable.basedir provide you path of the project.You can check the absolute path of jar in Effective POM tab of pom.xml

Comment: By the way is ${basedir} the same as ${project.basedir} in pom?

Comment: yes you can say.both will work in above case.Ur pblm solved ?

Comment: my pleasure to help u.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is usually to use a Maven Repository Manager (e.g. Nexus) and then deploy your library to this Maven Repository Manager.

See here for how to set up the settings.xml file:
http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Answer (score 0):

How to create maven dependency for your local jars..

1)Create a maven project of the program of which you have to create the jar.

2)Add required groupid and artifact id and version no.

3)Then after writing the java files export it as a jar.

4)Now open other project in which you want to add local jar dependency.Go into its pom.xml and add dependency with the group id,artifact id and version which u had entered in the jar project.

5)Maven clean and install.Now that jar file will be available in your local repository. :)